# Problems with null(?) Date criteria in a Process Builder flow.

Tags: criteria

We've got different statuses for a record where we want to back fill date markers that an event happened. If I "Held Interview" then obviously I also "Contacted" a given person. Sometimes the Process Builder works, other times it flat out fails and so far I'm at a loss as to why. The criteria for the action seems correct as does the action. But we're getting close to just switching over to using Apex instead to do a field evaluation.

I've tried enabling Recursion, that didn't seem to help either, but I could look at again.

Not necessarily looking for a silver bullet just looking for ideas of things to check. Attaching a screenshot of the criteria. All of the fields are different date fields. The end action is simply setting some of those date fields with the current date value if the particular event permutation happens.

[image: date criteria]

Comment: There are still a lot of known issues with Process Builder SF is working on. Do you have an error message you can share?

Comment: Is checking for isEmpty or isBlank an option? Generally, that's often a preferable solution for many types of fields vs null.